# Polling a restful service in Talend

Tags: loops, talend

I am building a job in Talend that queries a restful service. In the job, I initiate a job and get a job ID back. I then query a status service, and need to wait for the job to complete. How would I go about doing this in Talend? I have been playing around with tLoop, tFlowToIterate, tIterateToFlow and tJavaRow components to try get this to work, but am not sure how to configure it.

Here's a summary of what I'm trying to do:

```
1. tRest: Start a job and get job ID
    |
    --> 2. tRest: Poll status of job
       |
        --> 3. tUnknown?: If the job is running, sleep and re-run Step 2.
               |
                --> 4. tRest: when the job is complete, retrieve the results
```

How would I set up step 3 above?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want something like

tInfiniteLoop --iterate--> (subjob for querying the service and determining if result is ready) --if (result is ready)--> (subjob for fetching the result) --on subjob ok--> tjava with "counter_tInfiniteLoop_1 = -1;" to leave loop (don't know of a better alternative)

I would advice to implementing a timeout or maximum number of lookups and maybe even an automatically increasing sleep time.